# ¿Como tomar un arreglo de una función y usarla en otra función (PHP POO)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

En PHP tengo una clase con ciertos métodos, `iniciar_sesion()` y `cerrar_sesión();`
Al momento de ingresar al metodo iniciar_sesion() creo una variable que me guarda un arreglo `$datos = array($sign->username);`

```
    public function iniciar_sesion(){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $pass = $this->input->post('password');
        $sign= $this->login_model->login($username,$pass);
if(!is_null($sign){
        $datos = array($sign->username);
echo json_encode(array('msj' => 'ok'));
}else{
echo json_encode(array('msj' => 'fail'));
}
    }
```

¿Como podría obtener los datos de la variable `$datos` en la función cerrar_sesion()?

```
public function cerrar_sesion(){
   var_dump($datos); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JDavid, el array se imprime vacío porque seguramente no estás invocando previamente al método `iniciar_sesion`, que es donde dicho array adquiere sus valores, según el código que has mostrado.

Como algún compañero ha comentado, lo correcto sería que la clase tuviese un miembro privado `$datos`, y yo diría que incluso un `getter` para obtenerlo.

Por lo general las clases no sacan información por pantalla, sino que devuelven valores, lo digo por el `var_dump` que veo en tu código, lo cual, supongo que es para prueba.

Si tú necesitas en algunos casos el valor de `$datos` sin tener que iniciar sesión, entonces lo que podrías hacer es asignarle su valor en el constructor de la clase. De ese modo, cuando se crea una instancia de la clase, `$datos` adquiere valores. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php 

class Sesion
{
    private static $datos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$datos = array("sign"=>"username");        
    }
    public function iniciar_sesion()
    {
        /*
          $username = $this->input->post('username');
          $pass = $this->input->post('password');
          $sign= $this->login_model->login($username,$pass);
         */
    }

    public function cerrar_sesion()
    {
        //return self::$datos; 
    } 

    public function getDatos()
    {
        return self::$datos;     
    }
}

    /*Prueba*/
    $objSesion=new Sesion();
    $arrDatos=$objSesion->getDatos();
    var_dump($arrDatos);
?>
```

**Resultado:**

```
array(1) {
  ["sign"]=>
  string(8) "username"
}
```

Aquí simplemente creamos una instancia de la clase, y luego invocamos al getter para obtener el valor de `$datos`.

---

Ahora veamos un ejemplo parecido al código de tu pregunta. Para que `$datos` adquiera sus valores, hay que llamar al método `iniciar_sesion`.

Aquí el método `cerrar_sesion` hace una llamada a `getDatos` después de haber cerrado la sesión. Este sería el procedimiento adecuado si: **(a)** siempre que cierres sesión necesitas obtener el valor de `$datos`; **(b)** en algunos casos necesitas obtener el valor de `$datos` independientemente de cerrar la sesión o no (en ese caso invocarías a `getDatos` sin tener que cerrar la sesión):

```
<?php 

class Sesion
{
    private static $datos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //self::$datos = array("sign"=>"username");        
    }
    public function iniciar_sesion()
    {
        self::$datos = array("sign"=>"username");        

        /*
          $username = $this->input->post('username');
          $pass = $this->input->post('password');
          $sign= $this->login_model->login($username,$pass);
         */
    }

    public function cerrar_sesion()
    {
        echo "Cerrando sesión ...".PHP_EOL;
        return $this->getDatos(); 
    } 

    public function getDatos()
    {
        return self::$datos;     
    }
}

    /*Prueba*/
    $objSesion=new Sesion();
    $objSesion->iniciar_sesion();
    $arrDatos=$objSesion->cerrar_sesion();
    var_dump($arrDatos);
?>
```

**Resultado:**

Es exactamente el mismo...

```
array(1) {
  ["sign"]=>
  string(8) "username"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar tu funcion `iniciar_sesion` deberia retornar algun valor, en este caso: `$datos`.

De esta manera:

```
public function iniciar_sesion(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $pass = $this->input->post('password');
    $sign= $this->login_model->login($username,$pass);
    $datos = array($sign->username);
    return $datos;
}
```

Lo siguiente seria cargar en cerrar_sesion ese llamado, para eso usaremos $this con el fin de referirnos a la misma clase.

```
public function cerrar_sesion(){
    $this->iniciar_sesion();
}
```

Comment: Hola @vaavDev, gracias por tu disposición, si,  tienes razón se debe de retornar un valor, pero el problema no es tánto eso, ni tampoco meter el método dentro de otro, sino que esos datos que guardo en la variable $datos los pueda utilizar en cualquier método que cree y es a lo que no he podido llegar... Agradeceria si tienes alguna otra alternativa que me pueda servir, un saludo.

Comment: @JDavid si en vez de ser una funcion que retorne, se le asignar directamente a un atributo de la clase?, algo como $this->datos_inicio = inicio_sesion()?

Comment: no me podria servir de esa manera, puesto que lo que estoy retornando (que no lo puse), no es los datos del arreglo sino un *echo json_encode(array('msj' => 'success')* es por eso quiero dar a entender que los datos de la variable *$datos* son 'independientes' por decirlo de alguna otra manera, para asi poder yo utilizar esos datos del arreglo en algun otro metodo si se da la ocasion... Entonces, unicamente necesito esos valores no el metodo completo en otro metodo porque no tendria sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es poder recuperar el valor del arreglo de la variable $sign->username desde cualquier punto del aplicativo, debes guardar este valor en una sessión. Es importante tomar en cuenta el uso de las funciones session_start() y 
session_destroy(), en el ejemplo te doy una breve explicación de su uso.

[Ver documentacion de uso de sessiones en PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

***Ejemplo:***

```
    <?php
class Session
{

    public function iniciar_sesion()
    {
        session_start();//Le dice a php que llame a los manejadores de sessiones de php, tanto de escritura y lectura 
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $pass = $this->input->post('password');
        $sign= $this->login_model->login($username,$pass);
        $_SESSION['userName'] = array($sign->username);
    }

    public function cerrar_sesion(){
        var_dump( $_SESSION['userName']); 
        session_destroy();//destruye toda la información guardada en una session, es importante para no dejar rastros del usuario logueado anteriormente
    } 
}


$session= new Session();
$session->iniciar_sesion();
$session->cerrar_sesion();


?>
```

Comment: Hola @Delcio, gracias por tu colaboración, he intentado hacer el código que has puesto pero al momento de ejecutar el metodo cerrar_sesion() me muestra un array vacio *array(0) { }*, verifique dentro del otro metodo y los datos si estan, ¿sabes alguna otra manera? te agradezco

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, favor validar

Comment: Hola @Delcio, no, sigue apareciéndome el mismo arreglo vació.

Comment: Podrias subir tu clase php a https://eval.in, aqui te paso el ejemplo en vivo de mi solución donde se visualiza la impresion de los valores.

https://eval.in/989989

Comment: Hola @Delcio, he mirado tu codigo y te pasa lo mismo, espero hagas el intento, si borras *$clase->iniciar->sesion()* y ejecutas el script te va arrojar un array vacio.

Comment: @JDavid por supuesto que debe arrojar ese valor, fijate que el valor de la variable $datos se setea en la funcion iniciar_session(). Si estas tratando de llamar a la funcion cerrar_session() antes de iniciar_session() el resultado sera un valor nulo siempre.

Comment: Ok entiendo, pero de igual manera me tocaría en cada método (si es el caso) llamar ambas funciones, y como comente a otro usuario ahora, los datos de la variable *$datos* son los que específicamente necesitaría, lo demás es propio del método que no necesito

Comment: Lo que necesitas entonces es guardar el dato en una session del servidor utilizando lo siguiente $_SESSION['datos'] =  array($sign->username);

para obterner el dato harias lo siguiente:

  public function cerrar_sesion(){
        var_dump(  $_SESSION['datos'] ); 
    }

Answer (score 0):

prueba guardando los datos en una session ( fuera del alcance de la instancia de la clase ) Por ejemplo:

```
public function iniciar_sesion(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $pass = $this->input->post('password');
    $sign= $this->login_model->login($username,$pass);
    if(!is_null($sign){
        $datos = array($sign->username);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['datos'] = $datos;
        echo json_encode(array('msj' => 'ok'));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('msj' => 'fail'));
    }
}

public function cerrar_sesion(){
        $recoveryDatos = $_SESSION['datos'];
        var_dump($recoveryDatos); 
    }
```

Por supuesto recuerda antes de llamar a la función 'cerrar_sesion()' que tienes que abrir una sesión con 'session_start()'